# Downgrading Angular 16 to 15

Tags: angular, downgrade

I have downgraded angular 16 to 15 but some components are still at original version 16.2.12 (animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms):

```
Angular CLI: 15.0.0
Node: 16.14.0
Package Manager: npm 8.3.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 16.2.12
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1602.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular      16.2.10
@angular-devkit/core               15.0.0
@angular-devkit/schematics         15.0.0 (cli-only)
@angular/cdk                       15.0.0
@angular/material                  15.0.0
@angular/material-moment-adapter   15.0.0
@schematics/angular                15.0.0 (cli-only)
typescript                         5.1.6
```

How do I remove all references to version 16.2.12?

My `package.json` look like the following:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "16.0.*",
    "@angular-material-components/moment-adapter": "^16.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.12",
    "@mat-datetimepicker/core": "^12.0.1",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^7.0.4",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "automapper-ts": "^1.9.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.33",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^16.1.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.13.3"
  },
```

The dev section is as follows:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.12",
    "@types/google-libphonenumber": "^7.4.28",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
```

Comment: can you post your package.json?

Comment: I have inserted partial package.json in my original question. There is no more attach button.

Comment: You need to downgrade all `@angular/*` package to v15. There are quite some missing.

Answer (score 0):

First install the angular 15 cli.

```
npm i -g @angular/cli@15
```

Then create a new angular project

```
ng new Angular15App
```

After creating run npm install

```
npm install
```

Now all your versions will be synced to angular 15, now install all the packages from your old project into the new project, this will give you the version numbers that suit angular 15

Finally once all the packages are installed, copy paste the `new package.json` version values into your original project, this will help you solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your package.json, the following packages need to be downgraded to angular 15

```
"@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "16.0.*",
"@angular-material-components/moment-adapter": "^16.0.1",
"@angular/animations": "^16.2.12",
"@angular/common": "^16.2.12",
"@angular/compiler": "^16.2.12",
"@angular/core": "^16.2.12",
"@angular/forms": "^16.2.12",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.12",
"@angular/router": "^16.2.12",
```

In the dev dependencies section, the following packages need to downgrade

```
 "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.10",
```

To downgrade first you need uninstall angular cli and then do the following command

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@15
```

You can find the version 15 from here

```
https://www.npmjs.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

first you can do like this, for downgrade version 16 to 15

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli
sudo npm install @angular/cli@15
```

and then check your angular version

```
ng version
```

if angular version 15, you need adjust your package.json, please adjust version with information from `ng version`,
but if you have repository angular version 15, you don't need adjust package again

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have downgraded one by one all packages from file package.json.
The version 15 is now working.
I have found and followed up this link: [link](https://blog.bitsrc.io/stop-using-npm-install-in-your-ci-cd-pipeline-ba0378bbebfb)